# AngularJS ng-change not calling function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui

I'm trying to get the content in a bootstrap popover to change when the user types something in the email text box. It seems that ng-change is not getting into the method `updateToolTip()`. I'm brand new to AngularJS. Any advice is appreciated.

html page

```
<div ng-controller="LoginController">

  <for name="form" ng-submit="login()">

    <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="user.email" value="{{user.email}}" ng-change="updateToolTip()" popover="{{emailMessage}}" popover-trigger="focus" popover-placement="right" required>

    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" ng-disabled="form.$invalid">Sign in</button>
  </form>

</div>
```

js

```
var loginModule = angular.module('loginModule', ['ui.bootstrap']);

// Controller for the login page
loginModule.controller('LoginController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.emailMessage = 'test';   

    $scope.updateToolTip = function() {

        $scope.emailMessage = 'asdfsadf';   
        console.log();
        console.log(' inside function');
        if($scope.user != null) {
            console.log('user not null');
            if($scope.user.email.$dirty && $scope.user.email.$error.email) {
                console.log('email dirty and error');
                $scope.emailMessage = 'Invalid Email!';
            } else if($scope.form.email.$dirty && $scope.form.email.$error.required) {
                console.log('emaildirty and required');
                $scope.emailMessage = 'Email Required';
            }
        }
    }
}]);
```

Comment: Can you create a plunker / jsfiddle so we can see it in action?

Comment: @Catfish without going into the depths of your code, are you using Jquery as well ? I had problems with the two woking together and finally moved the JS loading into the page footer

Comment: Not related to the question, but when using ng-model on an input, there is no need to set the value attribute as it will be handled by ng-model!

Comment: can you post the complete HTML ?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/2pPR60ybLwv1VvIudy8m?p=preview

Comment: @avrono i removed the jQuery declaration since i'm not using it. It didn't do anything different.

Comment: @jpmorin noted and removed from my code.

Comment: Is the opening "form"  tag misspelling have anything to do with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `form` name to `name="user"`. Like

```
 <form class="form-signin" name="user" ng-submit="login()">
```

Since you use form model like `user.XXXX`.

Demo <kbd>**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/E6vfPLZVOkZEXq67EavF?p=preview)**</kbd>

**[EDIT]**

I would write validation like this:

```
<input 
   type="email"
   name="email"
   class="form-control"
   placeholder="Email address"
   ng-model="user.email"
   popover="{{emailMessage}}"
   popover-trigger="focus"
   popover-placement="right"
   required
   >
    <span class="error" ng-show="mailform.email.$error.required">required</span>
    <span class="error" ng-show="mailform.email.$error.email">invalid email</span>


    <input 
    type="password"
    name="password"
    class="form-control"
    placeholder="Password"
    ng-model="user.password"
    value="{{user.password}}" required    >
    <span class="error" ng-show="mailform.password.$error.required">required</span>
```

Demo 2 <kbd>**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/dNdVIXk2quJKau27XRMF?p=preview)**</kbd>

And maybe this example might help you as well: Demo 3 <kbd>**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/81jgWv?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: @jpmorin this is a answer on his question, check the PLunker I posted, after define proper name for `form`, `ng-chage` works as expected

Comment: Thanks for that. I really like this trick i see in your code `{{user|json}}`. Can you explain why when i'm typing in an email address, as you type, `user.email` disappears until it's a valid email?

Comment: @Catfish that happens because angular supports `input` with `type="email"`.  This type does not become valid until it is a valid email. The model is not set until it is valid.

Comment: @Catfish see "Demo 3", you don't need controller at all